# How to check if user is a fan of facebook page by using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I want to check if user is a fan of a specific facebook page, I have tried many times with FQL but the response is always null:

```
FB.api({
        method:     'fql.query', 
        query:  'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=user_id AND page_id=page_id'
    }, function(resp) {
        if (resp.length) {
            alert('A fan!')
        } else {
            alert('Not a fan!');
        }
    }
);
```

I've tried with user table is running good:

```
FB.api(
          {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
          },
          function(response) {
            alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
          }
        );
```

I've just checked in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/. It seems that facebook does not support FQL, so what can I do ?

I really appreciate your help.

**UPDATE**
I've just tried Graph API solution but the result is array null:

```
FB.api('/100005548217775/likes/329849167104448',function(response) {
                    if( response.data ) {
                        if( !isEmpty(response.data) )
                            alert('You are a fan!');
                        else
                            alert('Not a fan!');
                    } else {
                        alert('ERROR!');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Facebook doesn’t allow “like gating” any more. And even if that is not what you are trying to do, you will most likely not get use of the permission `user_likes` approved.

Comment: @CBroe So how can I do to check an user is liked a fan page or not ?

Comment: You are _not supposed_ to check that at all. You are only allowed to use the user’s likes for stuff that actually offers them a benefit – such as looking at all their likes, and based on that recommend pages/content that they might also like. But for just checking whether the user likes a specific page, you will not get the use of the necessary permission approved by FB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an v2.0 app, you can't use FQL at all, because it's deprecated. Furthermore, you're using the wrong `method` parameter, which is also deprecated.

The official endpoint for FQL is

```
/fql?q={url_encoded_query}
```

where `{url_encoded_query}` is the url encoded FQL query.

I'd recommend you skip FQL, and go with the standard Graph API funcitonality (which is future proof):

```
/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}
```

Note that you'll need the `user_likes` permission in the access token to be able to get any result.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#pagelikes

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've just update my question, could you take a look ? I'm not sure the way I'm using Graph API is correct or not.

Comment: What does "is null" mean? An array with `[]`? If so, have you granted the `user_likes` permission? Also, you can use `/me/likes/{page_id}` when you're passing an access token

Comment: Yes, It an array with []. How can I get `user_likes` permission ?

Comment: So, the array is empty, not null. That's a big difference :-) See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer:

```
FB.login(function(response){
            if(response.status=='connected'){
                FB.api('/me/likes/' + 216524221773305, function(api_response)
                 {
                    if(api_response.data.length > 0){
                        setLocation('<?php echo $this->getConnectUrl() ?>');
                    }else{
                        jQuery('#facebook-like-popup').show();
                    }
                 });
            } 
        }, {scope: 'user_likes'});
```

There is one thing that make me confused that is: When I've just liked a fan page then check the result still return `Array[]`. It seems that Facebook doesn't update data immediately. Not sure what I think is right ?

Answer (score 0):

This will not either work as you need user_likes permissions from facebook, you can try something else, lets say that the page you want to find out if a user liked is

https://www.facebook.com/pg/Poulamecom-159391200925483/likes/?ref=page_internal

1)visit page 
2)view source
3)find "likeStatus" inside source, if its true then user liked page, if false then user did not like the page
4)"visit page" could be done automatically by a script and check if  likeStatus":true or likeStatus":false